# List mp3 files from specific folder inside storage device

Tags: android

I have been building simple mp3 player everything is going well the code which fetches all mp3 files from storage device's works well.

```
Uri media = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
```

My question i need to load mp3 files only from sdcard kalid folder. i have tried this code but its not loading mp3 files from kalid folder.

```
File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/kalid");
Uri media = Uri.fromFile(path);
```

i have also tired this code

```
File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/kalid");
Uri media = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(String.valueOf(path));
```

I think no one is understanding my question here is full source code
 ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();

```
Uri media = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath("Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ kalid+");


    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!=0";
    Cursor cursor = resolver.query(media, PROJECTION, selection, null, null);
    if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Music List Empty");
        return false;
    }

    mMusicList.clear(); // clear

    int count = cursor.getCount();

    for (int i = 0; i != count; ++i) {
        if (!cursor.moveToNext()) {
            break;
        }
        //Log.d(TAG, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)));
        // Add to ArrayList
        mMusicList.add(new Music(
                cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM)),
                cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST))
                ));

    }
    cursor.close();
```

Comment: Indeed. That code does nothing. That only make an uri from a path.

Comment: @greenapps so show me the way thanks

Comment: No thanks. And please contact a code writing service. This site is for helping you with your problems. Please describe them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after trying so many things i have listed mp3 files from kalid folder here is the source code.

```
 Cursor cursor = resolver.query(media, 
PROJECTION, 
MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " like ? ",
new String[]{"%kalid%"}, null);
```